# Import and export or credentials, cookies and data between browsers doesn't work in Debian Bullseye

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, debian, opera

I already had a solution, the LastPass Extension, but still, I want do know about this issue.

I want to export and import not only the passwords, but all the cookies and data.

The Firefox ESR, Opera and Chrome does't detect each other.

Decided to install the Flatpak version, Firefox updated and Opera also does't detect each other.

There is a solution for this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for all the browsers, but at least for Chrome passwords importing is disabled by default and needs to be enabled via this flag:

```
chrome://flags#password-import
```

It should still be able to export natively.  You may or may not need to rely on extensions or non-native solutions for the other data, or manually transfer said data.

Also note, for some browsers (e.g., [Vivaldi](https://forum.vivaldi.net/topic/34139/how-to-import-export-passwords-between-vivaldi-and-chrome/18?_=1639286986708)) having a non-default installation path also breaks the standard import functionality.  In other words, if you have a non-standard version of Chrome (e.g., Chrome Beta, Chrome Dev, etc.) installed to *their* default path (i.e., *not* Chrome Stable's standard path), Vivaldi will not "see" your Chrome data at the import step.

Lastly, I've heard that the standard import function is not functional on Linux platforms, and need to be performed manually.